# what is missing that prevents my IDLE from working?

Tags: python, tkinter

Installed Ubuntu 10.10 and Python 2.5.5.  IDLE did not start from the terminal so I went into the Python interpreter and did "import _tkinter".  The package was not found.  After searching a bit, I found that Ubuntu/debian might not include _tkinter so I proceeded to "sudo apt-get install python-tk" as per my searches.

Still the interpreter cannot find _tkinter.  What next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved in another thread.  The solution is to install tk-dev before installing Python 2.5.5 (on Ubuntu 10.10 which came with Python 2.6).

[TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY environment variables on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553869/tk-library-and-tcl-library-environment-variables-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

There's an IDLE package in the Ubuntu software center that you can install. Install that and IDLE will work.

**UPDATE**

It is indeed in the Ubuntu software center on Ubuntu 10.10. Evidence:
[image]

Comment: Looking into Ubuntu Software Center > Get Software > Developer Tools > IDE, there is no IDLE on my system but other IDEs are mentioned.

Comment: @Broiyan Just search IDLE, I don't think they consider it an IDE

Comment: @broiyan if you search for exactly `idle` it will come up, unless you did a nonstandard install of Ubuntu or something strange like that. It's also under Developer Tools > IDE.

Comment: Thanks I found it under Developer Tools.  I installed IDLE from the Ubuntu Software Center. Still the interpreter cannot import _tkinter.  Idle invoked from the terminal command line also says "no module named _tkinter".

Comment: The IDLE that I selected to install was not version numbered. (I saw some numbered 2.6 and higher.)  I am using Python 2.5.  After installing, I went into Synaptic Package Manager and I can see that there are 2 versions of IDLE installed.  One is 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 and the other is 2.6.6-5ubuntu1.  This could be a problem because I'm on 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Use Synaptic Package Manager (System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager).  Search for "idle".