# TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY environment variables on Ubuntu

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get _tkinter to import into Python.  I suspect it may be due to not having values defined for the environment variables TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY.  This is as it stands after using apt-get for python-tk, tcl, and tk.  If I have to set the environment variables manually, what would I set them to?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and Python 2.5.5.

Comment: 'import Tkinter' works for me out of the box on 10.10 ? Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @A A: he's using some installation of Python 2.5; I suspect you are using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: I am trying to get IDLE to run.  It fails because it cannot import _tkinter.  Interactively I also fail to import _tkinter because it is not found.  A search indicated that TCL/TK might not be included with Ubuntu 10.10 so I used apt-get but it did not help with the problem.  The back of the Mark Lutz Python book says the TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY may need setting but I don't know what to set them too.

Comment: so why do you say you are using Python 2.5? It's not even included in Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I installed Python 2.5.5.  When I invoke Python it says 2.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY should not be necessary. I suspect you are invoking a Python interpreter different from `/usr/bin/python`, or `/usr/bin/python` has been changed to point to a different Python interpreter than the one that goes with the `python-tk` package. Ubuntu 10.10 ships with Python 2.6 by default.

**Edit**: To build Python 2.5 with Tk support, make sure the tk-dev package is installed before running configure. Also check the end of the build output what other modules have not been built, and consider installation the relevant header files. Make sure that your installation does not overwrite /usr/bin/python, e.g. by installing into /usr/local (which is the default for configure).

Comment: Interesting.  I need to use Python 2.5 for Google App Engine.  Should I uninstall Python 2.6 before installing Python 2.5 (plus TK plus TCL)?

Comment: Where did you get Python 2.5 from? Uninstalling Python 2.6 will likely break your system completely.

Comment: Well, I failed to uninstall Python 2.5 because of a dependency problem.  "Package dependencies cannot be resolved.  This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."

Comment: I installed Python 2.5 from python.org.

Comment: deleted comment w.r.t. Ubuntu vs Windows

Comment: @broiyan: See my edit. If you build Python yourself, you also need to make sure _tkinter is built. You cannot use Ubuntu's _tkinter for Python 2.6 on Python 2.5.

Comment: Final notes: Martin's solution is correct.  To summarize: if you want to use Python 2.5.5 with Ubuntu 10.10 your _tkinter may be missing or somehow associated with Python 2.6 which was included in Ubuntu 10.10.  Your IDLE will not work.  To fix the problem install tk-dev, re-install Python 2.5 from the "configure" step.